# @teamhive/ngx-tooltip Not sure how to show() tooltip programmatically

Tags: angular, tooltip

I need to be able to turn on and off this tooltip as I mouse around, because I'm attaching it to nested elements (I already detect when the cursor goes deeper for other purposes).

The documentation states that there are some methods: "Some commonly used options are made available through element properties." including `show()` and `hide()` but I'm not sure how to apply those, as the options are applied as a directive and I never actually have a variable that represents the tooltip.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@teamhive/ngx-tooltip

There are no examples showing the use of these methods, that I can find.

I saw that there's a `TooltipInstance` class that has a `show()` method, but when I try to inject it to manipulate it, I get this, which I'm sure denotes that I'm all kinds of wrong:

```
  src/app/components/shared/asset/asset.component.ts:79:30
    79     private tooltipInstance: TooltipInstance,
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This type does not have a value, so it cannot be used as injection token.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) annotation to get a reference to your tooltip instance on your template, and then use that to show/hide the tooltip. I imagine that would look something like this:

***.component.html**

```html
<div #myTooltip="ngxTooltip" ngxTooltip [tooltipAllowHtml]="true" tooltipContent="<span> … </span>"> … </div>
```

***.component.ts**

```js
@ViewChild('myTooltip', {static: true}) myTooltip: NgxTooltip;

...

showTooltip() {
    this.myTooltip.show();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to help. `ERROR TypeError: this.myTooltip.show is not a function`. `myTooltip` is an `ElementRef` and the type coercion in the `@ViewChild` isn't adding the necessary methods to that. The `div` that the ref is on isn't the actual tooltip; the tips are created as `body`-level `div`s, if that matters..

Comment: My apologies, you're correct. It's always difficult to write up code without a stackblitz to test. I've amended the template reference (`#myTooltip="ngxTooltip"`) so that the `@ViewChild` annotation should treat the element as an instance of the exported ngxTooltip directive. You may need to double check what the `exportAs` value is on the directive, because it could be different, I'm just taking a guess based on Angular conventions. If it's different you'll need to replace the `ngxTooltip` to whatever the `exportAs` value is on the directive.

Comment: So, it turned out that I was able to `@ViewChild(TooltipDirective)` to access the directive and thus the methods. However, the methods didn't really operate the way I expected so I ended up with rolling my own. :) Thank for the help; I wouldn't have googled up a directive children otherwise.